# Bearer token undefined(Authentication)

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, bearer-token

I am using authentication with jwt in my mern stack project.The registration works fine, but whenever I try to login I get this message in the console:

```
message: "Success"
token: "Bearer undefined"
```

Here's my code for server.js which contains the authentication API in the back:

```
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const user = req.body;

  const takenEmail = await User.findOne({email: user.email})
  
  if(takenEmail) {
    res.json({message: "Email has already been taken"})
  } else {
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)

    const dbUser = new User({
      firstName: user.firstName.toLowerCase(),
      lastName: user.lastName.toLowerCase(),
      passportNumber: user.passportNumber.toLowerCase(),
      email: user.email.toLowerCase(),
      password: user.password
    })

    dbUser.save()
    res.json({message: "Success"})
  }
})
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    
  const userLoggingIn = req.body;

  
      User.findOne({email: userLoggingIn.email.toLowerCase()})
      .then(dbUser => {
          if (!dbUser) {
              return res.json({message: "Invalid Email or Password"})
          }
          bcrypt.compare(userLoggingIn.password, dbUser.password)
          .then(isCorrect => {
              if (isCorrect) {
                  const payload = {
                      id: dbUser._id,
                      email: dbUser.email,
                      firstName:dbUser.firstName,
                      lastName:dbUser.lastName,
                      passportNumber:dbUser.passportNumber
                  }
                  jwt.sign(
                      payload, 
                      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
                      {expiresIn: 86400},
                      (err, token) => {
                          return res.json({message: "Success", token: "Bearer " + token})
                      }
                  )
              } else {
                  return res.json({message: "Invalid Email or Password"})
              }
          })

      })
  
})

function verifyJWT(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.headers["x-access-token"]?.split(' ')[1]

  if(token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.PASSPORTSECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if(err) return res.json({
        isLoggedIn: false,
        message: "Failed To Authenticate"
      })
      req.user = {};
      req.user.id = decoded.id
      req.user.email = decoded.email
      next()
    })
  } else {
    res.json({message: "Incorrect Token Given", isLoggedIn: false})
  }
}
```

Here's the code for Login Component(frontend):

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
     const [password, setPassword] = useState("");


     async function loginUser(event) {
         event.preventDefault();

         const form = event.target;
         const user = {
             email: form[0].value,
             password: form[1].value
         }

         const response = await fetch('/login', {
            method: 'POST',
             headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
             body: JSON.stringify(user),
         
         }) 

         const data = await response.json();
                  
         if(data.token) {
            localStorage.setItem("token", data.token)
            alert("Login successful!")
         } else {
             alert("Invalid email or password.")
         }
}

       useEffect(() => {
           fetch("/isUserAuth", {
               headers: {
                   "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token")
               }
           })
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then(data => data.isLoggedIn ? navigate("/"): null)
       }, [])
```

And finally the code for Register component(frontend):

```
async function onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const response = await fetch("/register", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                firstName,
                lastName,
                passportNumber,
                email,
                password,
            })
        })

        const data = await response.json()

        if (data.message === "Success") {
            alert("Registeration successful!")
            navigate('/login')
        } else {
            alert("Email already taken.")
        }
        
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/isUserAuth", {
            headers: {
                "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token")
            }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data.isLoggedIn ? navigate("/"): null)

        
    }, [])
```

The .env file containing the secret keys:

```
JWT_SECRET=secret123
PASSPORTSECRET=secret123
```

I think the error comes from the secret keys in the .env file.However, I don't recognise the problem. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: In the callback of the `jwt.sign` did you try to check what is in the `err` variable? Maybe this will give you a hint on what is wrong.

Comment: I didn't require the .env file in the server.js and thus,JWT_SECRET was not defined. Thanks for you help anyway! @MichalTrojanowski

Answer (score 0):

within your `server.js` file the **token** should have been generated by **jwt.sign** method like this:

```js
const token = jwt.sign(
  payload,
  process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  {
    expiresIn: 86400,
  }
);
// save user token
user.token = token;

// user
res.status(200).json(user);
```

Comment: `jwt.sign` also accepts a callback, so it doesn't have to be assigned to a variable.

Comment: @nos nart Thank you for your resoponse. However, my mistake was that I didn't require the .env file in my server.js

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski Yes, it doesn't have to.

Comment: Requiring the .env file was my "gotcha". After I added that in, it worked like a charm. Example: `const dotenv = require('dotenv')`